# eventhub publishing very slow

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am using these code snippets to publish events on an eventhub:

```
// ...

var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, EventHubName);

// ...

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None };
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evt, serializerSettings));
var eventToBeSend = new EventData(data) {PartitionKey = "Bla"};
eventHubClient.Send(eventToBeSend);
```

This seems to be very slow (i.e. the eventHubClient.Send method invocation takes quite a bit of time). Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to group up events to send and use **SendBatchAsync()** . As long as your batch size does not exceed the 256k limit of one operation, that could potentially speed up the message delivery significantly.

Also, just making sure that you also persist your QueueClient - they are created through something named a *MessagingFactory* wich provides internal connection management, so once created, keep your QueueClient up.

There is a good page on service bus performance:

https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/documentation/articles/service-bus-performance-improvements/

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common bottleneck when sending a big amount of data to event hub is a not proper set of the throughput units.

Not very sure how much time is taking this request and the size of every package you are sending, but you should check this official documentation before any assumption.

**What are Event Hubs throughput units?**

You explicitly select Event Hubs throughput units, either through the Azure portal or Event Hubs Resource Manager templates. Throughput units apply to all event hubs in an Event Hubs namespace, and each throughput unit entitles the namespace to the following capabilities:

- Up to 1 MB per second of ingress events (events sent into an event hub), but no more than 1000 ingress events, management operations or control API calls per second.
- Up to 2 MB per second of egress events (events consumed from an event hub).
  Up to 84 GB of event storage (sufficient for the default 24-hour retention period).
- Event Hubs throughput units are billed hourly, based on the maximum number of units selected during the given hour. You can automatically increase the number throughput units as your usage increases.

Comment: If the TUs are not set properly it could turn into a bottleneck and decrease the performance.