# Azure EventHub: Send Async performance

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

I have pretty naive code :

```
    public async Task Produce(string topic, object message, MessageHeader messageHeaders)
    {
        try
        {
            var producerClient = _EventHubProducerClientFactory.Get(topic);
            var eventData = CreateEventData(message, messageHeaders);

            messageHeaders.Times?.Add(DateTime.Now);
            await producerClient.SendAsync(new EventData[] { eventData });
            messageHeaders.Times?.Add(DateTime.Now);
            //.....
            Log.Info($"Milliseconds spent: {(messageHeaders.Times[1]- messageHeaders.Times[0]).TotalMilliseconds});
        }
    }

    private EventData CreateEventData(object message, MessageHeader messageHeaders)
    {
        var eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)));
        eventData.Properties.Add("CorrelationId", messageHeaders.CorrelationId);

        if (messageHeaders.DateTime != null)
            eventData.Properties.Add("DateTime", messageHeaders.DateTime?.ToString("s"));
        if (messageHeaders.Version != null)
            eventData.Properties.Add("Version", messageHeaders.Version);

        return eventData;
    }
```

in logs I had values for almost 1 second (~ 800 milliseconds)
What could be a reason for such long execution time?

Comment: What is in `CreateEventData(message)`

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686936/eventhub-publishing-very-slow

Comment: @PeterBons, added in the question

Comment: @IanMercer, not sure, in this case I couldn't use grouping events to send them in batch, and I'm caching EventHubProducerClient (through _EventHubProducerClientFactory)

Answer (score 3):

The `EventHubProducerClient` opens connections to the Event Hubs service lazily, waiting until the first time an operation requires it.  In your snippet, the call to `SendAsync` triggers an AMQP connection to be created, an AMQP link to be created, and authentication to be performed.

Unless the client is closed, most future calls won't incur that overhead as the connection and link are persistent.  **Most** being an important distinction in that statement, as the client may need to reconnect in the face of a network error, when activity is low and the connection idles out, or if the Event Hubs service terminates the connection/link.

As Serkant mentions, if you're looking to understand timings, you'd probably be best served using a library like [`Benchmark.NET`](https://benchmarkdotnet.org) that works ove a large number of iterations to derive statistically meaningful results.

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring the first 'Send'. That will incur some overhead that other Sends won't. So, always do warm up first like send single event and then measure the next one.

Another important thing. It is not right to measure just single 'Send' call. Measure bunch of calls instead and calculate latency percentile. That should provide a better figure for your tests.